# crawler fail, i can not copy dynamic info in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, function, web-crawler

I am doing a crawler which take information on net, im using php class DOM, but i got a problem..

I cant take information on javascript dinamic functions, i dont know how to explain it, you can see an example on i mean here:

http://www.europafm.com/frecuencias/

If you click on the map you can see information which i want to copy but cant with DOM class, do you know another way to take this information?? I dont mind if have to change programming language, im now working with php.

greetings and thanks in advance, this is my first post here and i hopefully not the last

Comment: Its basically not possible without a great deal of effort and running each page in a browser.  Just index the html & be happy :)